# Firebase Structuring Complex List Data Without Creating Multiple Nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have following 2 ways to construct data. Want to know which is correct way as in each of the case I'm coming across different limitations.

**Case 1** : Nested Objects - Here single object is pushed maintaining all records related to recipient. All data related to recipient can be fetched in single "Query" can be passed to Firebase-Ui (FirebaseRecyclerAdapter)

**Problem**: Adding data to "servicesArrayList". Because it's index based (0,1,2,...). New push would add pushId (-KgJoRXVUP_-Z0gLhIWy). Breaks structure(refer code below). Now crashes while retrieving data. (Problem while deserializing data as structure is expecting ArrayList)

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    Recipient recipient = dataSnapshot.getValue(Recipient.class);
}
```

**Question**: Is there way to maintain index on new push  or while first push itself it can be structured in some different way ?

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();

Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(RECIPIENT_NODE)
            .child(uid)
            .orderByChild("billNo")
            .equalTo(135);

recipient // parent Node

   2R1Q8qKEPHXFU1OiMq5TyxHBaZa2 // uId

     -KgJhMAWADwownv5tck6  // push Ids
     -KgJhMAWADwownv5tck6
     -KgJoD77HQK-yACD_EuB
     -KgJoRXVUP_-Z0gLhIWy
     -KgJob82t47PvTjfTtig
     -KgK-N_Av_2kmmQS0Ulx

     -KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b // Recipient Data
          billNo: 135
          billingMonth: "July 2017"
          childName: "xyz"
          date: "29/03/2017"
          fineAmount: 0
          paymentStatus: "UNPAID"
          pushId: "-KgNu-fVWwFDLnRENj_b"
          recipientEmail: "abc@gmail.com"
          recipientName: "Abc C."
          servicesArrayList
                       -0                 //added when recipient object was pushed
                          -amount: 1000
                          -charges: "1000"
                          -noOfSessions: 1
                          -serviceType: "Speech And Language Assessment"
                      -1                  //added when recipient object was pushed
                          -amount: 1200
                          -charges: "600"
                          -noOfSessions: 2
                          -serviceType: "Group Sessions"

                      -KgJoRXVUP_-Z0gLhIWy // added as an update to exsiting list (errrr ! now structure is breaking.)
                          -amount: 1200
                          -charges: "600"
                          -noOfSessions: 2
                          -serviceType: "Group Sessions"

          vat: 0
```

**Case 2**: Maintain 2 different structures for Recipient and Services.

**Problem**: Have to fire 2 different "Queries". Merge 2 datas separately and then pass it to normal adapter (can't use Firebase-ui). Monitor using ChildListener / ValueeventListener. 
Mapping using FOREIGN KEY and more tedious.

**Question**: Is there a way to use a single query to get data from both nodes ?

[image]

So I need an answer to **Question 1** and **Question 2** and need to understand which is the correct way ?

Answer (score 2):

Firebase recommends **avoiding nesting data (Case 1)** and instead **flatten the data structure (Case 2)**. You can read more in [Structuring your Firebase data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)

Quoting Firebase itself 'This is a necessary redundancy for two-way relationships. It allows you to quickly and efficiently fetch memberships, even when the list of users or groups scales into the millions or when Realtime Database security rules prevent access to some of the records.

This approach, inverting the data by listing the IDs as keys and setting the value to true, makes checking for a key as simple as reading /users/$uid/groups/$group_id and checking if it is null. The index is faster and a good deal more efficient than querying or scanning the data'.

So, I guess Case 2 is the way to go.

Comment: Yes I went through Firebase docs. If you see in case 2, I have to make too many Firebase calls if I want to display list of recipient with some service details or If I want to use filter based on services for recipients. It's just too cumbersome !

Comment: @NayaneshGupte have you asked the Firebase guy ?